# Is there any way to know how Swift calculates hashValue?

Tags: swift, hash

I recently found that the code below ends up with hash collision.

FYI, I'm using XCode 9.4.1 (9F2000), which uses Swift 4.1.2

```swift
import Foundation

let lhs = "あいうえおあいう21あいうえ"
let rhs = "あいうえおあいう22あいうえ"
let percentEncodedLhs = lhs.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlPathAllowed)!
let percentEncodedRhs = rhs.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlPathAllowed)!

let lhsHashValue = lhs.hashValue
let rhsHashValue = rhs.hashValue
let lhsPercentHashValue = percentEncodedLhs.hashValue
let rhsPercentHashValue = percentEncodedRhs.hashValue

print(lhsHashValue == rhsHashValue)
print(lhsPercentHashValue == rhsPercentHashValue)

/*
 Output:

 false
 true
 */
```

I know that hash collision can happen in some circumstance, but I couldn't find **how Swift calculates hashValue for String**.

For example, Java calculates hashCode of String like:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode()

Is there any official explanation or maybe some assumptions?

Comment: You can view the source code at swift.org. Somewhere in there will be the implementation of `String hashValue`.

Comment: You may be able to find some versions of Swift implementation of `hashValue`, but it may change in the future. For example, your code generated output `false`/`false` in Swift 4.2/Xcode 10 beta 4 (with just a few runs). With [Hashable Enhancements](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0206-hashable-enhancements.md) implemented in Swift 4.2, `hashValue`  generates some unpredictable value. You just need to know that _hash collision can happen_ at any occasion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I couldn't find how Swift calculates hashValue for String

Why couldn’t you? Swift is open source. If you are interested, read the source.

https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/111499d2bfc58dc12fcb9cd1ce1dda7978c995b7/stdlib/public/core/StringHashable.swift